# "Invalid cookie path" with Zend\Session when setting cookie_path

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm trying to set the cookie path to my local domain:

```
$config = new \Zend\Session\Config\StandardConfig();
$config->setOptions(array(
    'cookie_path' => '.jt.martyndev',
));
$sessionManager = new \Zend\Session\SessionManager($config);
\Zend\Session\Container::setDefaultManager($manager);
return new \Zend\Session\Container('jt_sso');
```

However, I'm getting the following exception:

```
Type: Zend\Session\Exception\InvalidArgumentException
Message: Invalid cookie path
File: /var/www/jt_sso/vendor/zendframework/zend-session/src/Config/StandardConfig.php
Line: 439
```

Why is my cookie domain not valid? It's fine. I've used it perfectly well in other apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are confusing `cookie_path` and `cookie_domain`. `cookie_path` should be set to a path below which the cookie should be valid, e.g. `/` (the default) or something like `/questions/`. `cookie_domain` is the one you set to a hostname.